# How do you get KeyEvents from an EditText softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keylistener, keyevent

I know how to get KeyEvents from a physical keyboard, but how do I get them from a soft keyboard?

This code does not work for a soft keyboard:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(keyCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you need the `TextChangedListener` (or use it as alternative method):

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {        
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {                   
    }       
};
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, TextWatcher() doesn't let you know when an 'enter' or 'linefeed' or 'done' is pressed -- as an indication that the user has completed the edits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    etField =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);

    etField.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
             // register the text when "enter" is pressed
             if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
             || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
             int timesPressed = event.getRepeatCount();
             //do something
        }
    });
}
```

OR

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
   //do something
})
```